# Comparing ElementCollections of enums with QueryDSL and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, enums, querydsl

We have 2 Entites: an Employee who speaks a set of languages and a Review that is conducted by an Employee.

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "employeeLanguage"
    @Column(name = "language")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.String)
    private Set<Language> languages;
}

@Entity
public class Review {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Employee reviewer;
}
```

Language is a simple enum:

```
public enum Language {
    DE,
    EN,
    ;
}
```

Now we want to query for specific subsets of reviews if they have a specific employee's languages already fully covered. (union of all Review.reviewer.languages in specificReviewsSubset contains all specificEmployee.languages)

We're trying this with the following query:

```
private BooleanExpression hasAllEmployeeLanguagesCovered (List<Review> reviews, Employee employee) {
    return new JPASubQuery().from(e)
        .where(e.eq(employee))
        .where(e.languages.any().in(
            new JPASubQuery().from(r).join(r.reviewer, e)
               .where(r.in(reviews)).distinct().list(e.languages.any()
        )
        .exists();
}
```

But we are getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Undeclared path 'e_languages_ed0e7'.
Add this path as a source to the query to be able to reference it.
```

How can we add e_languages to the path? Afaik this only works if we would have a QLanguage and join language on e.languages. We could generate this by adding @Embeddable to Language but then hibernate complains about a missing no args constructor on Language.

Answer (score 0):

So far the only workaround we found was to ditch @ElementCollection and instead introducing an EmployeeLanguage entity that just holds a reference to the employee and a single enum value. This code produces the same db schema as the one in the question with the difference that querying languages now is possible:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Getter @Setter
    private Set<EmployeeLanguage> languages;
}

@Entity
public class EmployeeLanguage implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Getter @Setter
    private Employee employee;

    @Id
    @Column(nullable=false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Getter @Setter
    private Language language;
}
```

Now this query works after a small restructuring:

```
private BooleanExpression hasAllEmployeeLanguagesCovered (List<Review> reviews, Employee employee) {
    return new JPASubQuery().from(el)
        .where(el.employee.eq(employee))
        .where(el.language.notIn(
            new JPASubQuery().from(r).join(r.reviewer, e).join(e.languages, el)
               .where(r.in(reviews)).list(el.language)
        )
        .notExists();
```

}